# Validate choice type in formular

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have this kind of ChoiceType Field

```
                'Answers',
                ChoiceType::class,
                [
                    'choices' => [
                        'foo' => true,
                        'fooBar' => false,
                        'fooB' => false,
                    ],
                    'expanded' => true
                ]
            )
```

How can i validate this in my controller ?

After i choose `foo`  for example.
Here

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        }
```

Comment: You want to check when the form is submit if foo is checked ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want ?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by 'validate'

Comment: I just want to output a text if the correct option from choices is sent

Answer (score 0):

You can access your choices variable like so :

If you use Request request in the parameter of your function you can use

```
$choices = $request->get('yourFormName')['choices'];
```

Or in your case, using your $form variable

```
$choix = $form->get('choices')->getData();
```

So use this to check if the result is what you want or not.

Comment: Hey i get null as a result from your first answer.

Comment: Indeed, gonna fix that,
You can use $request->request->all() to see how the parameterBag looks like and use it as you would any array